# Swapping nsmutabledata

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have one UIViewController containing a UITableView. Along with this I have 3 buttons and 4 Mutablable arrays.

Array "prime" is the primary datasource for the table view.

When I hit button a , b or c I write

```
prime= a

[table reloadData];
```

or

```
prime= b

[table reloadData];
```

The problem I have is that after say 2 button pushes prime is not equal to either a or b. It contents now contain the contents of a "and" b and it's contents will continue to accumulate after every assign.

How can I make 1 nsmutuablearray switch its contents to be that of another?

I know I can just remove all objects and then add more. I more wanted to know if its possible to make prime be a pointer to a b or c?

Comment: From what you state in your question there is not enough informationto solve the issue. Are you manipulating the contents of prime in any other part of the code?

Comment: no I'm not. It's purley just a data source

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:
prime = [a copy];

Comment: If he just copies the contents of every array he wants to show his app will start leaking lots of memory, since he shouldn't be manipulating prime (or at least that's what i understand from the description)

Comment: Well, you'd release the current copy first before doing the next one.